# Non-orthogonal Nested ANOVA

Tags: anova, nested-data, nested-models

I am running a nested statistical analysis of variance on a field study I preformed. Unfortunately due to the conditions of the field it is non-orthogonal nested design where the number of sub-factors are not even across across main factors. Currently the design is set up  where Site is nested with habitat and habitat is nested within location, the issue is the number of sites within the 3 habitats and the number of habitats within the 2 sites differs. How do I account for this in a nest ANOVA?

I have provided a schematic of the design below.
[image]

Comment: Which vectors/functions are non-orthogonal? The  rows/columns of the design matrix?

Comment: You might find [multilevel models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_model) relevant.